# More Precise timer than Stopwatch?

Tags: c#, kinect, clock, stopwatch

I'm trying to have a stopwatch start and stop when recording positions for the Kinect:

```
   //process x and y coordinates
   public void calculateJoints(Skeleton skeleton)
    {          
        Joint rightHand = skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight];
        Joint leftHand = skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight];
        rightX = rightHand.Position.X;
        rightY = rightHand.Position.Y;         

    }

//start the stopwatch (tried to use a greater time between positions 1 and 5 vs 1 and 2
  public void processJointsAndRepeat(Skeleton skeleton)
  {
        startTime();
        while (numPositions < 5)
        {   
             calculateJoints(skeleton);
             numPositions++;
        }
        stopTime();
        double tempTime = calculateTimeElapsed();
  }

   //calculate time in milliseconds
   private double calculateTimeElapsed()
    {
        long milliseconds = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        return (double)milliseconds;
    }
```

But whenever I try to put in the x, y, and time values with time as the key, it throws an error for duplicate keys. When I retrieved the value of tempTime, it only showed 0.

Is this a problem with my code, or do I need a more precise stopwatch?

I realize that getting a time for something that is 30 fps is difficult, so if you have any other suggestions, that'd be great! I'm basically just trying to calculate the average velocities between points to adjust the playback speed of an audio file. Thanks!

Comment: What does `Stopwatch.IsHighResolution` return?

Comment: You are measuring code that executes in **nanoseconds**.  Yes, ElapsedMilliseconds is always going to return 0.  What you are doing makes little sense without intentionally slowing down the code to human time.  Use a Timer or Thread.Sleep().

Answer (score 2):

Stopwatch is wrapper around timer with higerst resolution on regular Windows box. You can use less fancy functions to get higer than MS resolution by using [Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedticks.aspx) and [Stopwatch.Frequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.frequency.aspx).

Note that your problem is probably not related to timers but rather some other code you did not show...